# How to join on null columns with Spark Sql?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running some queries with `join`s using Spark Sql 3.1 where the same columns in both tables can contain `null` values like:

```
select ...
from a
join b
on a.col_with_nulls = b.col_with_nulls
and a.col_without_nulls = b.col_without_nulls
```

However the query when it comes to `null` values is not working in the `on` condition. I have also tried with:

```
select ...
from a
join b
on a.col_with_nulls is not distinct from b.col_with_nulls
and a.col_without_nulls = b.col_without_nulls
```

as suggested in other solutions here but I keep on get the same result. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [<=>](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#_10) or [eqNullSafe()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.eqNullSafe.html) in order retain nulls in join.

Comment: `<=>` returns same results as `is not distinct from`